# arcpy FeatureClassToFeatureClass fails with "Could not write value to output field"

Tags: arcpy, feature-class

I have a Python script using arcpy for ArcGIS 10.7.1 that is failing on the `FeatureClassToFeatureClass` line, below.

These three lines are quite straightforward:  Add a TEXT field, give the literal text value `DN` to that text field for every feature, then copy the feature class to a new feature class.

```py
        tmpSchemeFC = "in_memory/tmpSchemeFC"
        tmpWEPCFC = "in_memory/tmpWEPCFC"

        #  Lots of other stuff happens here, but it's difficult to see how any of it might be relevant to the problem

        arcpy.AddField_management(tmpSchemeFC, "Scheme", "TEXT")
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(tmpSchemeFC, "Scheme", "'DN'", "PYTHON")
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(tmpSchemeFC, os.path.dirname(tmpWEPCFC), os.path.basename(tmpWEPCFC))
```

However, the copying of the feature class fails, because it reckons that the value in the new TEXT field is not valid for the destination feature class, despite having no problems in using the same value in the source feature class and the fact that both feature classes should be identical.  Full error trace is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "R:\Admin\Scripts\BuildWEPCPoints.py", line 203, in <module>
    main()
  File "R:\Admin\Scripts\BuildWEPCPoints.py", line 183, in main
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(tmpSchemeFC, os.path.dirname(tmpWEPCFC), os.path.basename(tmpWEPCFC))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.7\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 1915, in FeatureClassToFeatureClass
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 001156: Failed on input OID 1, could not write value 'DN' to output field Scheme
Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).
```

I have tried specifying a `field_length=50` in the `AddField` but that didn't help.  I have also double-checked that there is not already an existing field with the same name (eg, already existing as a Double) by doing a `print [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(tmpSchemeFC)]` both before and after adding the new field, so I can clearly see that the new field is created successfully and did not exist before.

Why does this error occur?

Comment: Perhaps ' "dn" ' in field calculator.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  In Python, aren't " 'DN' " and ' "DN" ' the same thing?

Comment: Same in Python, might be different in field calculator.

Comment: Well the field calculator in this case specifies that it is a Python expression.  But I've tried it with the quotes the other way around anyhow, just to be sure.  No joy, I'm afraid.  :-(  Same error:  `ExecuteError: ERROR 001156: Failed on input OID 1, could not write value 'DN' to output field Scheme`